# Image manipulation in R

Tags: python, linux, r, image, image-processing

I'm a newbie in R and I got to implement a project in which part of it involve image manipulation (eg: load/write jpeg files, resize images, rotate, crop (apply masks?), etc.).

I've spent some time "googling" but didn't find relevant texts (tutorials) teaching how to manipulate images using R. The closest I found was a package called adimpro and its documentation.

Question is: What functions [packages] people use to manipulate pictures in R? Any tutorial [beside help/manual] of how to use them would be apreciated.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I'm restricted to use R or R + Python.

Comment: I don't know anything about the R project, but `opencv` is a great library.  Googling for "opencv R" gives [this project](http://www.ohloh.net/p/r-opencv) which looks promising.

Comment: What about calling ImageMagick/convert with the `system` command?

Comment: The raster  package (coupled with rgdal) is pretty good for load/write, resize, rotate, crop, but whether it covers your etc. depends on what that is.

Comment: Another alternative is the [EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.pdf) package

Comment: daroczig: read carefully my question and you will note that I said restricted to R and Python.

Answer (score 2):

When you are looking for a package providing a set of functions, the best is to start with [CRAN Task views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/). In your case, there is nothing specific about image processing, but if I choose [Medical Imaging](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html), it leads to a package called [adimpro](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adimpro/index.html), and others.
Maybe you could find something interesting this way.

Another option is to look at [the entire list of packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) and search for occurrences of words like "image" or "imaging".

Comment: As I said in my question: I had already considered using adimpro.